# Can I use the ansible.cfg in my Git repo when using AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I have a Git repository with contains `ansible.cfg` in the root of the directory. Can I use that `ansible.cfg` when provisioning using AWX or Tower? How?

If that is not possible, can configure ansible.cfg settings in AWX?

Or should I use the local `ansible.cfg` on the AWX server?

Comment: Which parameter are you trying to set there ? If you're trying to set roles/collections path, see https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/4675

Comment: My mistake. AWX is using the ansible.cfg in root directory on default. BTW, I think that bug 4675 is fixed now. In any case my AWX 16.0 is finding roles etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `ansible.cfg`, if it is in the root directory.

Be aware, that some configuration are overridden by AWX/Tower.

[See documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/tipsandtricks.html#locate-and-configure-the-ansible-configuration-file)